# How to convert a string to an array by splitting at newline but only on non-empty strings in ZSH?

Tags: arrays, macos, shell, scripting, zsh

I have a little bit of a problem.  I am trying to convert a string to an array in a zsh script and it works but it seems to also convert empty strings into an array with 1 empty string in it.

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
CurrentHour=$(date +%H)
CurrentMinute=$(date +%M)
CurrentDate=$(date +%F)


MeetingTitles=("${(@f)$(icalbuddy -ic Family -nc -iep title eventsFrom:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:00:00 +01:00" to:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:59:59 +01:00" | cut -c 5-)}")
MeetingHour=("${(@f)$(icalbuddy -ic Family -nc -tf %H -iep datetime eventsFrom:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:00:00 +01:00" to:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:59:59 +01:00" | cut -c 14-15)}")
MeetingMin=("${(@f)$(icalbuddy -ic Family -nc -tf %M -iep datetime eventsFrom:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:00:00 +01:00" to:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:59:59 +01:00" | cut -c 14-15)}")
echo ${#MeetingTitles[@]}
if [ ${#MeetingTitles[@]} = 0 ]; then
        say "Hey Alexander, you have no calendar events in the next hour." -a 106;
else
        say "Hey Alexander, just a reminder that you have the following calendar events in the next hour" -a 106
        for ((i = 1; i <= $#MeetingTitles; i++)); do
                say "At "$MeetingHour[i] $MeetingMin[i]" you have an event titled "$MeetingTitles[i] -a 106;
        done
fi
echo ${#MeetingTitles[@]}
```

As can be seen I am using the

`("${(@f)$(your_command)}")`

method to convert the string returned by icalbuddy into an array so I can clean it up and use it to announce the events using the say command in MacOS.

The problem is the if statement is never true because this method of creating the array seems to make an array even if the string is empty so when I count the array it is always at least 1.

I need to figure out a way of setting the $MeetingTitles string to an array only if it is not empty but I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

The two echo statements are just for debugging the array count - both return 1 but any attempt to print it yields and empty string.

I am a bit rusty with shell scripting so there may be some obvious issues here I have missed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

I have no one line solution for your problem and I assume there is none. Your input has one delimiter so it is quite logical to evaluate to at least one empty element.

In general you could store the command output in a variable and only split if not empty.

But in your case it might be easier to just modify your if statement to

```
if [[ -z "${MeetingTitles[1]}" ]; then
```

Just check if the first element is empty. If you expect your command to return more elements but the first can be empty just check also that it is the only element.

Also you might want to rethink the usage of `(@f)`. With the '@' included any empty line in the command output will result in an empty array element which doesn't seem to be useful in your case. With only `(f)` empty lines (or more precisely consecutive delimiters which is new line here) do not create empty elements.

Comment: Yes, simplifying seems to make sense here, I was going to recommend something like `cmd_producing_output | wc -[cwl]` (take your pick from `[cwl]` (`man wc`) ). Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `A` flag in addition to double quotes and the `@` flag:

```
array=( "${(@fA)$( your_command )}" )
```

When the result of `$( your_command )` contains no newline characters, the `f` flag won't be able to split the string and the result remains scalar, and a double quoted scalar expansion isn't removed from a list of words. The `A` flag converts the substitution to an array, even if it would otherwise be scalar. That allows the empty word to be removed, like how `"$var[@]"` doesn't expand anything for an empty array.

In case you are okay with discarding any empty elements, you can omit some quotes:

```
array=( ${(f)"$( your_command )"} )
```

Comment: Appreciate this - I found the alternative use without the @ before you managed to post your answer but it is the solution I used as it works fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out with just a minor tweak, I changed:

```
MeetingTitles=("${(@f)$(icalbuddy -ic Family -nc -iep title eventsFrom:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:00:00 +01:00" to:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:59:59 +01:00" | cut -c 5-)}")
```

to:

```
MeetingTitles=(${(f)"$(icalbuddy -ic Family -nc -iep title eventsFrom:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:00:00 +01:00" to:"$CurrentDate $CurrentHour:59:59 +01:00" | cut -c 5-)"})
```

It is a subtle change - replace ("${(@f)$(command)}") with (${(f)"$(command)"}) which causes it to skip empty lines and thus not create an array if the output is empty (because the first line will always be empty).

Not sure if it is the most elegant solution - but it seems to be working.